# move_base pointcloud data format

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm getting the error

```
[ERROR] [1545413307.824637530]: Client [/move_base] wants topic /mmWaveDataHdl/RScan to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/PointCloud/d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca], but our version has [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181]. Dropping connection.
```

My costmap_common_params.yaml has:

```
observation_sources: mmwave_radar

mmwave_radar: {sensor_frame: base_radar_link, data_type: PointCloud2, topic: /mmWaveDataHdl/RScan
, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

I submitted an issue to the github page and got told that it accepts PointCloud2 by default and the issue was closed.

When I search for this issue I find people saying it's not compatible and having to use an old EOL conversion package.

They can't both be true. Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311316/move_base-pointcloud-data-format/) by [Wezzoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/35617/wezzoid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-12-21**:
Just to confirm, what datatype is `/mmWaveDataHdl/RSCan`?

**Comment by [Wezzoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/35617/wezzoid/) on 2018-12-24**:
Yeah it's definitely pointcloud2. I left it over weekend, started it up just now to double-check before answering - it mysteriously works! I now have costmaps! I swear I didn't touch my launch files or anything. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

False alarm - it's working

---

Originally posted by [Wezzoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/35617/wezzoid/) with karma: 76 on 2018-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0